# How to add the background css into this jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

As you can see in my fiddle here, http://jsfiddle.net/HsKpq/460/ I am trying to show the images into the 
`$('#header').css('background-image',..................).fadeTo('slow',1);`

How can I do this?

```
var img = 0;
var imgs = [
    'http://www.istockphoto.com/file_thumbview_approve/9958532/2/istockphoto_9958532-sun-and-clouds.jpg',
    'http://www.istockphoto.com/file_thumbview_approve/4629609/2/istockphoto_4629609-green-field.jpg',
    'http://www.istockphoto.com/file_thumbview_approve/9712604/2/istockphoto_9712604-spring-sunset.jpg'
];
// preload images
$.each(imgs,function(i,e){var i=new Image();i.src=e;});

// populate the image with first entry
$('img').attr('src',imgs[0]);


var opacity = 0.1; // change this for minimum opacity
function changeBg() {
    $('img').fadeTo('slow',opacity,function(){
        $('#header').css('background-image',..................).fadeTo('slow',1);
    });
}



setInterval(changeBg,5000);
```

Comment: You might get better results if you don't just downvote every person trying to help you. If their answers aren't solving your issue, it's **your job** to provide them clear info as to what's still going wrong or what you desire more explanation on.

Answer (score 0):

Don't know what you were trying to do with the background image and then populating the first image to a non-existent element.

Here is an updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/HsKpq/464/

But this may be what you are looking for to show the images :

```
var $h_image = $('#headerImage');

function changeBg() {
    $h_image.fadeTo('slow',opacity,function(){
        $h_image.attr('src', imgs[Math.floor((Math.random() * 3))]).fadeTo('slow',1);
    });
}
```

You also need to change your HTML to this :

```
<div id="header"><img id="headerImage"/></div>
```

Comment: hmm interesting. How to avoid showing the same image in sequence?

Comment: I have a lot of images in my page. How to make it to the specific one of the header?

Comment: @Fataoulas you can set an id to your image - http://jsfiddle.net/HsKpq/464/

Answer (score 0):

You can do it without img elements, using backgound css property, like here:

```
var img = 0;
var imgs = [
    'http://www.istockphoto.com/file_thumbview_approve/9958532/2/istockphoto_9958532-sun-and-clouds.jpg',
    'http://www.istockphoto.com/file_thumbview_approve/4629609/2/istockphoto_4629609-green-field.jpg',
    'http://www.istockphoto.com/file_thumbview_approve/9712604/2/istockphoto_9712604-spring-sunset.jpg'
];
// preload images
$.each(imgs,function(i,e){var i=new Image();i.src=e;});

var img = imgs[0];


var opacity = 0.1; // change this for minimum opacity
function changeBg() {
    $('#header').fadeTo('slow',opacity,function(){
        $('#header').css('background-image', 'url(' + img + ')').fadeTo('slow',1);
    });
}

setInterval(changeBg,5000);
```

Comment: it is always showing the first image

Comment: For now I have to downvote your answer

Comment: You need to cycle the image counter in your _changeBg()_ function. Also, watch out for redeclaring variable names; you've got _var img_ declared twice.